# Python - Asynch Multiprocessing from RabbitMQ Consumer

Tags: python, multiprocessing, rabbitmq, python-multiprocessing

I have a Python program that acts as a consumer for RabbitMQ. Once it receives a job from its queue, I want the program to split the job up using multiprocessing, but I'm running into issues with the logistics of multiprocessing.

I've simplified the code for readability.

My RabbitMQ consumer functionality:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue="JobReader", durable=True)
logging.info('Waiting for messages..')


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    job_info = json.loads(body)

    logging.info('Start Time: ' + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

    split_jobs = split_job(job_info)

    process_manager.runProcesses(split_jobs)

    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
```

My multiprocessing functionality:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import multiprocessing
import other_package


def worker_process(sub_job):
    other_package.run_job(sub_job)


def runProcesses(jobs):
    processes = []
    for sub_job in jobs:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_process, args=(sub_job,))
        processes.append(p)

        p.start()
```

Naturally, I can't do `if __name__ == '__main__':` because it is within a function.

I'm not sure if there is a workaround for this with multiprocessing, or if I'm just approaching this the wrong way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this is possible, I suggest to split jobs before putting them to queue. Then just run few consumers in their's own processes. If such a logic does not work for you then explain your issues in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor the `multiprocessing` piece so that you initialize its state from your main script:

```
import process_manager
...

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    job_info = json.loads(body)
    logging.info('Start Time: ' + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    split_jobs = split_job(job_info)
    manager.runProcesses(split_jobs)
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager = process_manager.get_manager()
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue="JobReader", durable=True)
    logging.info('Waiting for messages..')
```

Then `process_manager` looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import other_package

def worker_process(sub_job):
    other_package.run_job(sub_job)

_manager = None

def get_manager(): # Note that you don't have to use a singleton here
    global _manager
    if not _manager:
        _manager = Manager()
    return _manager


class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    def runProcesses(self, jobs):
        self._pool.map_async(worker_process, jobs)
```

Note that I use a `Pool` instead of spawning a `Process` for every single job, because that probably won't scale well.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a lot more sense. Thanks!